# How to concatenate one numpy element and one demension array?

Tags: numpy

```
a=np.array([1,2,3])
b=np.array([5,6,7,8])
c=np.array([8])
d=9
```

I want to composite a new array:

```
np.array([2,7,8,8,9])
```

So type code :

```
newlist=np.concatenate((a[1],b[2:4],c,d))
```

But hint error:

```
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Is single value that sliced from a np.array regarded as one dimesional array or a number?

In general, How to compose number and one dimensional array into an one demension array or list?

Comment: I would suggest using `np.r_` : `np.r_[a[1],b[2:4],c]` or `hstack` : `np.hstack((a[1],b[2:4],c))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `np.concatenate()` into `np.hstack()`:

```
np.hstack((a[1],b[2:4],c,d))
```

[np.hstack()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) takes a sequence of arrays and stacks them horizontally to make a single array.

Comment: `hstack` first loops through all the args and makes sure they are atleast 1d, then does `concatenate`.